# Buying Individual MiniFigures

Tags: minifigures, shopping

I was big into LEGO bricks when I was a kid (now 33), and now my son is getting into them. I'm a huge collector of things (not a hoarder, a collector), and, like father, like son, he wants to collect the minifigures, past or current.

I assume eBay is a great place for these but the prices probably tend to rather high.

Then while searching, I found [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/), which seems like a pretty good place to start.

Is this the truly best place to buy them, or are there other places just as good for minifigures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, BrickLink is by far going to be your best bet if you are looking for specific minifigures. Make sure you create a wanted list with all the minifigs you want, then quire by shop to see which seller(s) have all or most of the minifigures you want. You can save significantly this way on shipping.

eBay is not so good for individual minifigures as the prices tend to be much higher than on BrickLink, however it is still a great place to shop for bulk minifigs. Deals are not as easy to come by as in the past as people have smartened up and most people know the value of LEGO.

I would suggest to pick a particular theme to collect and be very specific on what you want to get, otherwise minifigure collecting can get out of hand pretty quickly. There are thousands of minifigures (all listed in the BrickLink catalog) - you can get a good selection for reasonable prices ($3-$5 per minifig), but in some themes having minifigs in the $20-$50 range and more is not uncommon (Star Wars is one of them).

Those little people can quickly take over your vallet. So best is to keep them under control for a fun and long-term hobby. ;)

Comment: Great suggestions! Yeah I thinking about going with the City theme, since we have an HO scale train set we put up each year and that seems like a good compliment for the train set.

Answer (score 1):

You can go on Firestartoys! They sell individual minifigures from all themes.